# Anchor to the footer doesn't work with jQuery in Wordpress in Webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a custom theme in Wordpress from scratch. Right now, I have done only the basics, such as creating the necessary .php files like index.php, footer.php etc..In my navigation menu I have a contacts anchor which is supposed to navigate you in the footer with animation. So, it is not working in Chrome and Safari, but works in Firefox. ( IE is not tested yet ). 
This is my jQuery and js files reference in **header.php** right after the meta tags:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/scrolling.js"></script>
<!-- End of Scripts -->

<!-- CSS links -->


<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

and this is my js file, pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  var v = $('div.nav-bar li a:last').addClass('scrollToBottom');
    v.click(function()
    {
    $('html,body').animate( {scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1600);
      console.log('hello');
      return false;
    });

});
```

My navigation bar is dynamically created with a class "nav-bar" in the functions.php. So, I added the console.log just to make sure that JS is working, and it does, the click function fires when you click in the contacts but nothing happens. Sorry I cannot upload any images. Also, it works fine when it is static but I don't want a static nav and it **does** work in Firefox....Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: "building... in Wordpress... from scratch" sooo funny :D

Comment: building a* Wordpress them from scratch..:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>` in your `header.php` file. [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) should be added to your `functions.php` file and hooked accordingly using `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'function_name')`.

Then you don't need to add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` either.

WordPress loads jQuery in [No Conflict](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) mode. so your jQuery should look like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
 // your code here
});
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your response I'll try that I will let you know!

Comment: hey do you mean something like this? http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes/#.UVmIqquzzUM

Comment: Yes, that's how you should add your scripts